# AMC 2012(Senior) Q28

Tags: geometry, contest-math

A quadrilateral with sides $15,15,15$ and $20$ is drawn with each vertex on a circle.Around this circle,a square is drawn,with each side tangent to the circle.What is the area of this square?

I know for sure that the area of square is more than $20^2$ because the radius is more than $20$ And how do I visualize this?

Comment: Do you mean that the quadrilateral is drawn **with** each vertex on a circle?

Comment: Yes,sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $DH$ is the trapezium height, notice that 
$$
EF=DH=\sqrt{DA^2-AH^2}=\sqrt{15^2-2.5^2}.
$$ 
On the other hand, if $r$ is the circle radius, we have:
$$
EF=OF+OE=\sqrt{r^2-10^2}+\sqrt{r^2-7.5^2}
$$
By comparing and solving for $r$ one gets $r^2=135$.

[image]

Comment: The second paragraph,where does the $10^2$ and $7.5^2 $ comes from?

Comment: $OF=\sqrt{OA^2-AF^2}$ and $AF=AB/2=10$. In the same way, $ED=DC/2=7.5$.

Comment: I see,I understand! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From the data, we see that this cyclic quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezium.

Splitting the trapezium into two triangles, sharing a common side $x$ which subtends angles $\theta$ and $180-\theta$ in each triangle respectively, we can apply the cosine rule and get $$x^2=625-600\cos\theta=450-450\cos(180-\theta)$$ from which we can deduce that $$\cos\theta=\frac 16$$ and $$x=\sqrt{525}$$
We need the diameter of the circumcircle, so applying the sine rule in the form $$\frac{a}{\sin A}=2R$$ we get the side of the square as $6\sqrt{15}$ so the area is...540

Comment: No calculator is allowed for this question.So,I can't use trigonometry...

Comment: you don't need a calculator for any of this!

Comment: Im lost at the deducing part.

Comment: @Arc, $\cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos\theta$.

Comment: I see.My teacher haven't teach further trigo yet but that's from the unit circle definition of cosine right?

Comment: Can I explain by saying the angle formed by $\theta$ is in the 2nd quadrant where it is $\cos$ negative right?

Comment: Yes, two points on the unit circle at angles adding up to pi will have the same $y$-coordinate and opposite $x$ coordinates.

Comment: $ \cos (\theta) =\frac 16 $ then how do you know the value of $\sine (\theta)$ for the sine rule? Do we have to use a calculator already?

Comment: Using a right angled triangle and Pythagoras, we get $\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{35}}{6}$